# Stable FTP client component for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, ftp

I need an ftp client which is able to run stably 24/7. It needs to run in windows XP and support Delphi. It would be nice if it support SFTP. We tried Indy and Smart Ftp client before. The version of Indy we used seems to have memory leak issue and Smart Ftp DLL crash occasionally. Well, my program needs to wake up ftp client every 20 minutes (or less) all day long and those FTP client components will crash/freeze eventually. Could anyone here recommend me a really stable FTP Client Component? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ICS [(Internet Component Suite)](http://www.overbyte.be)  is very good, although it doesn't support SFTP. I have an FTP client that runs every few hours daily without problems, and the author provides really comprehensive demos.

Answer (score 3):

I've used Indy too for a similar FTP application with lots of problems and converted it to [nSoftware's IP*Works!](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/) with great success and would recommend it any day.  They've got an SSL version too of the components but haven't used them.

Comment: What kind of problems did you have with Indy?

Answer (score 2):

Our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/) offers both FTP/FTPS and SFTP components for Delphi. For both protocols all protocol-defined features are supported (unlike other components which implement only basic functionality).

Answer (score 2):

What version of Indy did you use?  I am not aware of any memory leaks in the TIdFTP component (which does support FTPS in Indy 10, but not SFTP, which is a different protocol).

Comment: I believe we were using Indy 9.I remember it will leak a small amount of memory each time.

Comment: The Indy 10 FTP component is very solid for me.  Perhaps you should look into upgrading Indy or your compiler. (what was the last compiler that Indy 9 came with?)

Comment: Well, I believe we used Indy 9 due to backward compatibility issues. But I will give Indy 10 a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the [Clever components](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/inetsuite/ftpclient.asp) components have been good and reliable for me. They sort out all the complicated bits and I get on with my work. They have some secure options, but FTP has various options so you'd have to check that they match your server.